# Django - language switching with query data

Tags: django, localization

Hi I have a search results page which returns queries form the database using this view:

```
def search(request):
show_results = False
# check if POST
if 'q' in request.POST:
    query = request.POST['q'].strip()
# check if GET (paginated)
if 'q' in request.GET:
    query = request.GET['q'].strip()
# check if query length is more than 2 characters and proceed
if query and len(query) > 2:
    # if there is a query string show results (as opposed to arriving without any POST/GET      
    show_results = True
    keywords = query.split()
    q = Q()
    for keyword in keywords:
        q = q & (Q(title__icontains=keyword) | (Q(keywords__icontains=keyword)))
        query_set = Article.objects.filter(q)
    # create a new paginator instance with items-per-page
    paginator = Paginator(query_set, 10)

    # get the page number from a get param if param is blank then set page to 1 
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1')) 

    # grab the current page from the paginator...  
    items = paginator.page(page)

    # update search counter with term
    try:
        term = Search.objects.get(term=query)
    except Search.DoesNotExist:
        # if not already in db, then add query
        term = Search(term=query)

    term.counter += 1
    term.last_search = datetime.now()
    term.save()

elif len(query) <= 2:
    short_string = True
else:
    pass
#render the template and pass the contacts page into the template  
return render_to_response('search_results.html',
                            locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the template:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" name=postlink   method="post">
    <ul class="lang">
         <li class="lang" style="color:gray">
                {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}

                    {% if lang.0 != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}">
                        <a href=# onclick="submitPostLink()">{{ lang.1 }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ lang.1 }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
        </li></ul>
</form>
```

The language switching works fine on all pages except one case. When I submit the language change data on the search results page where no results have been returned (i.e. empty queryset), I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /search/
local variable 'query' referenced before assignment
```

I think I need to tweak the view slightly, but I'm not sure where. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Traceback:

```
traceback: `Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/search/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'journal',
'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware')

 Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
 111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,       **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sam/public_html/django- projects/galapagos_research/../galapagos_research/journal/views.py" in search
 40.    if query and len(query) > 2:

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /search/
Exception Value: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `query` if `q` isn't in POST or GET. Since that's the only place where this error would appear, you must not be passing in `q`. An empty QuerySet wouldn't cause this error.

To be sure, it would help to have the line that triggered the error (the traceback - please).

```
def search(request):
    show_results = False

    query = None # set default value for query

    # check if POST
    if 'q' in request.POST:
        query = request.POST['q'].strip()

    # check if GET (paginated)
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q'].strip()

    ###########################
    # was `query` defined here if 'q' isn't in POST or GET? 
    ###########################


    # check if query length is more than 2 characters and proceed
    if query and len(query) > 2: # error probably on this line?
```

Comment: Yes, if query is not defined at line 40, it means 'q' was not in GET or POST. Provide a default for if 'q' isn't pased to GET or POST. For example, set `query=None` on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

At the start, query is never set to a default.

```
if 'q' in request.POST:
    query = request.POST['q'].strip()
# check if GET (paginated)
if 'q' in request.GET:
    query = request.GET['q'].strip()
```

Then in your elif, you try to determine the len() of query which isn't defined anywhere yet if 'q' is not in GET or POST.

```
elif len(query) <= 2:
    short_string = True
```

Comment: Accept Yuji's answer, since he got the answer in before me :)

Comment: ok, if I do default query at the start: `query = None`    then it solves the problem. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Write it in the easiest/most understandable way for when you re-read it. If checking for the existence of query in the elif is easier to understand, do that. If setting query = None is easier, do that. You could also change your first to if statements to be `if/elif/else query=None`, since you're never going to have a request that is POST and GET at the same time, you can use the elif.